# error while using the pocketsphinx package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic and I am trying to run the follwoing command

```
roslaunch pocketsphinx robocup.launch
```

and I got that error every time

```
setting /run_id to e5e01de0-9b34-11e7-8bfa-a4173173d1ff
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [26196]
started core service [/rosout]
process[recognizer-2]: started with pid [26203]
[INFO] [1505603716.914387]: Launch config: gconfaudiosrc
/home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py:68: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher('~output', String)
[INFO] [1505603716.924332]: Starting recognizer... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 177, in <module>
    start = recognizer()
  File "/home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.start_recognizer()
  File "/home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 80, in start_recognizer
    self.pipeline = gst.parse_launch(self.launch_config)
glib.GError: no element "vader"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/core.py", line 467, in signal_shutdown
    h()
  File "/home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py", line 131, in shutdown
    gtk.main_quit()
RuntimeError: called outside of a mainloop
[recognizer-2] process has died [pid 26203, exit code 1, cmd /home/shehabaldeen/catkin_ws/src/pocketsphinx/nodes/recognizer.py __name:=recognizer __log:=/home/shehabaldeen/.ros/log/e5e01de0-9b34-11e7-8bfa-a4173173d1ff/recognizer-2.log].
log file: /home/shehabaldeen/.ros/log/e5e01de0-9b34-11e7-8bfa-a4173173d1ff/recognizer-2*.log
```

I have the pocketshpinx installed and the sphinxbase as well
the error is same as [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKrMi936rWAhVDVxQKHVQZD-MQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fanswers.ros.org%2Fquestion%2F205091%2Fpocketsphinx-recognizerpy-does-not-work-in-ros-indigo-and-ubuntu1404%2F&usg=AFQjCNFREURdOm_iOBJpXJTpCSTxO22MzQ) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKrMi936rWAhVDVxQKHVQZD-MQFggvMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fanswers.ros.org%2Fquestion%2F217312%2Fproblems-with-pocketsphinx-for-speech-recognition%2F&usg=AFQjCNFrhDlE8DwH5q48iUBskINwYU4Tnw) and I saw the answers says to run this command which I have done

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-gconf
```

I tried also to run

```
 sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx'
```

and still having the same error if any one have suggestions or any one can help please

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271060/error-while-using-the-pocketsphinx-package/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://answers.ros.org/question/246247/speech-recognition-packages-for-ros-kinetic-kame/ and https://answers.ros.org/question/263623/pocketsphinx-package-on-kinetic/

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1